# Count the months between two dates in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, datediff

I have a `data.table` like the following:

```
ID   start_date   end_date
1    2015.01.01   2016.02.01 
2    2015.06.01   2016.03.01
3    2016.01.01   2017.01.01
```

I would like to get the following:

```
ID   start_date   end_date    Months_passed
1    2015.01.01   2016.02.01  13
2    2015.06.01   2016.03.01   9
3    2016.01.01   2017.01.01  12
```

I was trying the following code:

```
DT[, Months_passed:= length(seq(from = start_date, to = end_date, by='month')) - 1]
```

but I get the error, that

> "Error in seq.Date(from = start_date, to = end_date, by = "month") : 
>     'from' must be of length 1"

Comment: Did you try `difftime`?

Comment: Yes, but the max unit of difftime is "weeks" :/

Comment: So divide by 4...

Comment: Or `time_length(period,unit="months")` from lubridate ?

Comment: All `start_date` and `end_date` in your sample dataset are the first day of the resp. months. How do you count months if the date is not the first day? E.g., the period 2015-01-24 to 2015-02-07 can be counted as 2 months (Jan. and Feb.) or as 0.5 months (14 days)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a possible approach using data.table. First, turn your dates to real date-format:

```
df[, 2:3 := lapply(.SD, as.IDate, format = "%Y.%m.%d"), .SDcols = 2:3]
```

Then, get the months that passed:

```
df[, months_passed := lengths(Map(seq, start_date, end_date, by = "months")) -1]
```

So basically you need to `Map` the start and end dates to `seq`.

The result is:

```
df
#   ID start_date   end_date months_passed
#1:  1 2015-01-01 2016-02-01            13
#2:  2 2015-06-01 2016-03-01             9
#3:  3 2016-01-01 2017-01-01            12
```